# Lightning - How to to get attributes of the event.target on press event in a component's controller?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

I need to get **attributes** of the `event.target` in a Lightning Component's controller, like if I click on `<a href...>` in component, I need to get the value of **href** in controller. How to get this?

Comment: did u try using plain javascript getAttribute method ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: @VamsiKrishna it worked. Thanks. Please post as answer so that I can mark it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an elements attribute value, you can simply use the native [Javascript getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) method.

```
element.getAttribute(attributename)
```